# Delphi Taskbar (Progress Status in Windows Tasbar) not working in Administrator Mode

Tags: delphi, progress, taskbar

I 'm Working with `TTaskbar` in my form.

Taskbar Progressbar not showing in Windows taskbar When I run the program as Administrator Mode or Use "Enable Administrator Privileges" at manifest File in Project Options (Application).

Steps to recreate:

1. Create a new VCL forms application, with Delphi 10.1 Berlin
2. In the main form, drop a `TTaskbar` and a `TTimer`
3. Set the `TTaskbar`'s `ProgressState` to `Normal`
4. Set the `TTaskbar`'s `ProgressMaxValue` to `30`
5. Add event handler for timer, and add this code to it:

.

```
  procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    Taskbar1.ProgressValue:= Taskbar1.ProgressValue + 1;
    if Taskbar1.ProgressValue >= Taskbar1.ProgressMaxValue then
      Taskbar1.ProgressValue:= 0;
  end;
```

When run like normal, the taskbar icon shows progress fine.

When run as Administrator, the taskbar icon shows no progress.

Note! The problem does not occur with Delphi XE7.

Comment: What version of Delphi are you using? What code are you using? Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem in action

Comment: It works fine in my app, admin or not. What are you doing differently?

Comment: I have managed to recreate this using Delphi 10.1 Berlin. Running the application like normal, it shows the progress. But running as administrator, no progress shows. Edited your question with steps to recreate.

Comment: @Remy Done and done.

Comment: @TomBrunberg I have the same issue with minimal code.

Comment: @Jerry Yes, with Berlin I can also reproduce it. Earlier I tested with XE7

Comment: PS - I only put the `.` in the question because there's a bug in the markdown parser causing it to treat the code block as an ordered list. The `.` just forces it to format the code.

Comment: See: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-14716

Comment: I wrote my own code to do this, against the simple windows interface. As usual, that looks like a sound approach.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. but I tested all of solutions that you said. NOT Worked. I use Delphi 10.1 Berlin Update 2. PLEASE NOTE: in normal state it is work; But it is not work in administrator mode.

Comment: Look at the question, how it has changed (by @JerryDodge). That is how a question should look like. Clear problem statement, **steps to reproduce**, version info. You have still not said, which version you are using. We have found out by trials, that it is Delphi 10.1 Berlin (possibly also in 10.2 Tokyo). Look at the entry in Embarcaderos quality portal (hint: see link in FredS comment) for eventual bug correction.

Comment: I see you edited your comment while I was writing mine. It is a bug in Delphi 10.1 Berlin. Go to the quality portal and read the comments there, I recall there was some kind of workaround mentioned.

Comment: thanks. I 'm looking from Embarcadero Site. If I take an answer, I put it in this page.

Comment: @Pouya any progress ? I have the same problem.